# Updating access table through matlab function update

Tags: sql, matlab

I'm looking for the right syntax to update records of an MS Access DB via Matlab 2014b, using the table object.

T = table(var1,...,varN,Name,Value).

When I connect to access ...

```
    %% update les tickets existants
    [~,~,idx_upd] = intersect(x_trade_id,trade_id);

    for i = 1:length(idx_upd);
        iloop = idx_upd(i);


    connSQL = database('','','','sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver',url); 
    setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat', 'cellarray');

    curs = exec(connSQL, 'SELECT * from prod_execs');

        if sum(idx_upd)>0;
        % liste de champs de la base à impacter
         xcDatabaseField = {'trade_id', 'trade_dt', 'isin', 'sec_name', 'rfq_id', 'taker_side', 'qty', 'underlying_ticker','exec_price','instr_ccy','maker_firm_name','taker_trader','account','client', 'amount'};

        T = table(trade_id(idx_upd), ...
                   trade_dt(idx_upd), ...
                   BBGisin(idx_upd), ...
                   BBGsec_name(idx_upd), ...
                   rfq_id(idx_upd), ...
                   taker_side(idx_upd), ...
                   qty(idx_upd),...
                   underlying_ticker(idx_upd),...
                   exec_price(idx_upd),...
                   instr_ccy(idx_upd),...
                   maker_firm_name(idx_upd),...
                   taker_trader(idx_upd), ...
                   account(idx_upd),...
                   client(idx_upd), ...
                   amount(idx_upd),...
                   'VariableNames',xcDatabaseField);


          strWhereclause =  strcat('WHERE prod_execs.trade_id = ''', T.trade_id,'''');
          update(connSQL,strTableName,xcDatabaseField,T,strWhereclause);

          close (connSQL);
          close(cursSQL);

        end

    end
```

and I have a nice red message:

> Error using database/update (line 102)
>   Input data must be a cell array, matrix, structure, dataset or table.
>
> Error in database/update (line 72)
>             update(connect,tableName,fieldNames,subdata,whereClause{i})
>
> Error in test (line 137)
>                 update(connSQL,strTableName,xcDatabaseField,T,strWhereclause);

Please help.

Or I may ask it another way : is there a way to update a set of records by selecting them like in 'ADO'?

Comment: A bit messy, but after skimming appears to contain necessary content needed for a solution

Comment: Could you elaborate. Is there any resolution possible ?

Comment: No this is just coming from first post reviews

Comment: Does someone know how to update a whole subset instead of record-by-record iterations ?

Comment: If it's using SQL as tagged by your post, then you can just use `UPDATE` to do so. Not sure for access though.

Comment: The answer : sql update is ok with a whole subset of rows and columns. The matlab syntax : update(conn,tablename,colnames,data,whereclause) 
Data MUST be a cellarray and not a table (even if Matlab doc says table is ok). I had to extract data without the table headers, (the VariableNames). it can be done through indexing ...

for ex : data to load to database is a row subset of a Table, indexed by a vector called idxUpd :

Whereclause = (strcat(' WHERE Id =''', Tref.Id(idxUpd,:),''''));
xUpdateData=Tref{idxUpd,xcDBField};
update(connSQL,strDBTable,xcDBField,xUpdateData,Whereclause);